# foreach loop checking a value has changed before moving on

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I have a foreach loop that looks like this,

```
<?php $current_question = "";  
    foreach ($question_and_answers as $qa) : ?>  
        <?php $current_question == $qa['current_question']; ?>  
        <?php if($current_question == $current_question) : ?>  
            <input type="text" name="question[]" value="<?php echo $qa['question']; ?>"/>  
        <?php endif; ?>  
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I am wanting to create an input field every time the loop hits a new question (a question gets returned numberous times, as a question can have numerous answers).  What I have done does not seem to work.

I think seeing the array I working with help,

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [question_id] => 2
            [question] => What is my name?
            [tests_test_id] => 2
            [answer_id] => 5
            [answer] => Simon
            [questions_question_id] => 2
            [correct] => true
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [question_id] => 2
            [question] => What is my name?
            [tests_test_id] => 2
            [answer_id] => 6
            [answer] => Dave
            [questions_question_id] => 2
            [correct] => false
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [question_id] => 2
            [question] => What is my name?
            [tests_test_id] => 2
            [answer_id] => 7
            [answer] => Fred
            [questions_question_id] => 2
            [correct] => false
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [question_id] => 2
            [question] => What is my name?
            [tests_test_id] => 2
            [answer_id] => 8
            [answer] => John
            [questions_question_id] => 2
            [correct] => false
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [question_id] => 3
            [question] => What is my surname?
            [tests_test_id] => 2
            [answer_id] => 9
            [answer] => Crawford
            [questions_question_id] => 3
            [correct] => true
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [question_id] => 3
            [question] => What is my surname?
            [tests_test_id] => 2
            [answer_id] => 10
            [answer] => Caine
            [questions_question_id] => 3
            [correct] => false
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [question_id] => 3
            [question] => What is my surname?
            [tests_test_id] => 2
            [answer_id] => 11
            [answer] => Rooney
            [questions_question_id] => 3
            [correct] => false
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [question_id] => 3
            [question] => What is my surname?
            [tests_test_id] => 2
            [answer_id] => 12
            [answer] => Ainley
            [questions_question_id] => 3
            [correct] => false
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [question_id] => 4
            [question] => What is my favourite colour?
            [tests_test_id] => 2
            [answer_id] => 13
            [answer] => Blue
            [questions_question_id] => 4
            [correct] => true
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [question_id] => 4
            [question] => What is my favourite colour?
            [tests_test_id] => 2
            [answer_id] => 14
            [answer] => Yellow
            [questions_question_id] => 4
            [correct] => false
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [question_id] => 4
            [question] => What is my favourite colour?
            [tests_test_id] => 2
            [answer_id] => 15
            [answer] => Green
            [questions_question_id] => 4
            [correct] => false
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [question_id] => 4
            [question] => What is my favourite colour?
            [tests_test_id] => 2
            [answer_id] => 16
            [answer] => Red
            [questions_question_id] => 4
            [correct] => false
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [question_id] => 5
            [question] => Who do I support?
            [tests_test_id] => 2
            [answer_id] => 17
            [answer] => Huddersfield Town
            [questions_question_id] => 5
            [correct] => true
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [question_id] => 5
            [question] => Who do I support?
            [tests_test_id] => 2
            [answer_id] => 18
            [answer] => Leeds United
            [questions_question_id] => 5
            [correct] => false
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [question_id] => 5
            [question] => Who do I support?
            [tests_test_id] => 2
            [answer_id] => 19
            [answer] => Manchester United
            [questions_question_id] => 5
            [correct] => false
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [question_id] => 5
            [question] => Who do I support?
            [tests_test_id] => 2
            [answer_id] => 20
            [answer] => Wolverhampton Wanderes
            [questions_question_id] => 5
            [correct] => false
        )

)
```

What I am trying to do, loop through the array, and everytime I meet a new question I want to outout a text input with the value of the question.

Comment: `Does not seem to work` is not a problem description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
<?php $current_question = "";  
    foreach ($question_and_answers as $qa) : ?>  
        <?php if($current_question == $qa['current_question']) : ?>  
            <input type="text" name="question[]" value="<?php echo $qa['question']; ?>"/> 
            <?php $current_question = $qa['current_question']; ?>  
        <?php endif; ?>  
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Please see my edit for a better description of what I am trying to do

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very strange, you probably have your reasons for writing it that way but let me rewrite it so I can take a better look:

```
$current_question = '';

foreach($questions_and_answers as $qa){

    $current_question == $qa['current_question'];

    if($current_question == $current_question){ ?>
        <input type="text" name="question[]" value="<?php echo $qa['question']; ?>"/>
    <? }

}
```

I see a couple of faults:

1. `$current_question == $qa['current_question'];` does nothing, this is a conditional and will return true or false, but it won't return to anything. I think you've got this mixed up with a definition: `$current_question = $qa['current_question'];`
2. `$current_question == $current_question;` will always return `1` because it's the same variable. I think you are trying to compare it to `$qa['current_question']`

This should be what you're looking for:

```
$current_question = '';

foreach($questions_and_answers as $qa)
    if($current_question == $qa['current_question']){ ?>
        <input type="text" name="question[]" value="<?php echo $qa['question']; ?>"/>
    <? }
```

Or in your code:

```
<?php $current_question = "";  
    foreach ($question_and_answers as $qa) : ?>  
        <?php if($current_question == $qa['current_question']) : ?>  
            <input type="text" name="question[]" value="<?php echo $qa['question']; ?>"/>  
        <?php endif; ?>  
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

This is still strange however, because you define `$current_question` as an empty string, so the conditional will only run if `$qa['current_question']` is empty. However your question is too vague to see what you mean exactly.

Comment: Please see my edit for a better description of what I am trying to do